C# How to read every line within a xmlnode
I have a XML file with different XMLnodes.
Normally I read every XMLnode and take action.
Now I have a XMLnode with more lines in the InnerText.
I want for every line take an action.
How can I read Line by Line and take the action?
My XML looks like:
<specificatie>
<ki>
<kr><![CDATA[text01                              text02  text03                      amount]]></kr>
</ki>
<si>
<sr><![CDATA[Omschrijving 1                    221.352  BlaBla                             12,10
Omschrijving 2                     37.720  BlaBla                              6,05
Omschrijving 3                  1.000.000  BlaBla                        3,00]]></sr>
</si>
</specificatie>

Now I have this code:
foreach (XmlNode mainNode in parseNode.ChildNodes)
{
    switch (mainNode.Name)
    {
        case "specificatie":
            foreach (XmlNode detailNode in mainNode.ChildNodes)
            {
                switch (detailNode.Name)
                {
                   case "ki":
                        foreach (XmlNode regel in detailNode.ChildNodes)
                        {
                            SpecTable.AddRow(new ocumentLine(string.Format("\x1B(s3B{0}\x1B(sd@", regel.InnerText), lineCount++));
                        }
                        break;
                    case "si":
                        foreach (XmlNode regel in detailNode.ChildNodes)
                        {
                            foreach (XmlNode regels in regel.InnerText)
                            {
                                if (firstOfTable) SpecTable.AddRow(new DocumentLine(string.Format("\x1B(s1S-----\x1B(s0S"), lineCount++));
                                SpecTable.AddRow(new DocumentLine(string.Format("\x1B(s1S{0}\x1B(s0S", regel.InnerText), lineCount++));
                                firstOfTable = false;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }


You have innertext with with multiple lines.  Best way is to use : StringReader reader = new StringReader(regel.InnerText).  Then : string line = ""; While((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null){..........}
